# Is it a best practice to put a login form in the website's footer?

Tags: login

I am really wondering if it a best practice to put a login form in the website's footer? There's a login link in the menu bar so I am not really sure if its still needed.

Comment: Depend on the purpose of the login, however best practice is to position the login in high traffic area (top banner, top nav, landing page, etc)

Comment: Thanks for your input! I was thinking, would any user actually gonna login in the form that is placed in the footer?

Comment: That also depends on the website, if the page is lengthy and the footer is hidden, then no use of having a login on the bottom, If the footer is fit in the usual screen size with login visible, there is a chance to use your login.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thank you so much NPN! :)

Comment: You can always make your top nav sticky so that it won't be hidden from the user.

Comment: I would say that a login form in the footer is certainly unorthodox but it's something you'd have to test with your users

Answer (score 1):

Think about the flow of your website. Do you expect your users to make it to the bottom of your page before you want them to register? If so, go for it.

If the main goal of your website is for existing users to login, I'd put it above the fold. If it's secondary to a more primary action you want your users to complete, put it in the footer of your website.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like a terrible idea. Footers are last resort navigation items and something like a login is a primary use case (probably).

I have no idea why you would consider this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this one is a good idea to put the login form in the footer part.
generally The header and footer are key elements of a websites, The header is the first thing that people will see when they land on your site. and explore to other pages from here. You already given a link of login in the header part, That's Good.

But Footer is mean to be **well organised and the links are clearly laid out under useful headings so that visitors can quickly find what they are looking for. It adds a splash of color with the social media icons, which encourages customers to stay in touch. So Don't put the Login form in Footer.**

On the other hand, We are going on with the look and feel of clean and Minimal so Don't repeat the login form / button in same page.